# Hovering over a popup nav menu and have a separate popup display based on which element in menu is being hovered over?

Tags: html, css, popup, hover

I'm working on a site that has hovering popup nav menu that works exactly the way I want. What I want in addition to the menu is to have another popup somewhere else on the page that contains specific information about the element that the user is currently hovering over. If no elements in the nav menu are being hovered over, I want the popups to be hidden.

I have a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apD26/5/)** that has everything I want except the additional popup field.

I've tried everything I can think of except a JavaScript solution (as I'm not fluent in JS), however, I don't mind a JS solution. I can fumble my way through JS and make occasional changes - I just can't create it.

This hovering popup menu works (full HTML and CSS in the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apD26/5/)**):

```
<ul>
    <li>Nav menu here
        <ul>
            <li>Sub menu items</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>More nav menu items</li>
</ul>
```

How do I get an additional popup field with specific-to-the-hovering-element relevant information, when hovering over one of the top-level menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can start with.
You can use JavaScript to hide and unhide the information.

Check this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/apD26/17/

**Sample JS :**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.info').hide();
        $('.parent').mouseover(function(){
            $('.info').show();
            $('.info').text($(this).attr('data-desc'));
        });  
        $('.parent').mouseout(function(){
            $('.info').hide();
        });        
    });
```

Instead of `$(this).text()` which i have used to show the text, you may store your description in a `data` attribute in each menu item and display that.

**EDIT**

Updated the JSFiddle and answer

Comment: I tried some of this:
`<li class="parent" data="This is Prod 2"><a href="#">Prod 2 (long)</a>`  
AND:
`$('.info').text($('.data').text());`  
  
But I just get a blank box. Your JS is definitely the exact direction I want to go!

Comment: You cannot retrieve an attribute value using `text()` function. For that purpose you need to use  `attr()` function.I have updated the answer. I hope this is what you are looking for.